# Confluent Kafka 5.3.2 broker fails during startup

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are currently in confluent 5.3.1 kafka, we need to upgrade to 5.3.2.
We use incubator helm charts to setup kafka nodes in k8's cluster.

We have customised image to include below in our docker file as shown below, basically we wanted kafka to run as a non root user.

```
    FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    ........

    RUN groupadd -g 1001 myuser
    && useradd -r -m -u 1001 -g myuser myuser
    && chown -R myuser:myuser /var/lib/kafka
    && chown -R myuser:myuser /var/log/kafka
```

With above it works with 5.3.1 but when I just change the version to 5.3.2 in above docker file, it fails as shown below;

```
  ===> User
  uid=1001(myuser) gid=1001(myuser) groups=1001(insight),3000
  ===> Configuring ...
  ===> Running preflight checks ...
  ===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
  Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /var/lib/kafka/data writable] FAILED !
```

I have made sure the folder permissions are same in both the cases.

This looks like a regression, Did someone face this issue? If yes, can you please let me know what is the solution ?

Many thanks.
Robin Kuttaiah

Comment: Did you find any solution?